# Error while initializing entityManagerFactory in Spring Boot 2 with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-entitymanager

Good morning,
I am facing a problem in starting a Spring Boot app due to the fact that the `EntityManagerFactory` bean could not be autowired by Spring boot.

I already looked at various answers here on SO and over the net but didn't find any solution.

The configuration consists in

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

which should contain also the implementation of the `entityManagerFactory` bean, by looking in the parent `pom` the dependency

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

is present, so it should not be a `NullPointerException`.

I Configured Hibernate and the Datasource in the `application.properties` file with

```
#Datasource related properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sr002
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

**principal errors** are

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to asynchronously initialize native EntityManagerFactory: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
```

in the code the `Entity Manager` is called with:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

I can't really figure out why the problem is there if the dependency is written in the parent pom.

**EDIT**

By digging deeper I found out that a parameter named `jdbc42Apis` is null in the `AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.class` and so it goes to execute a line

```
JavaVersion.getMajorVersion() >= 1 && JavaVersion.getMinorVersion() >= 8
```

where is thrown a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1`. Someone who knows where this could come from? On the internet I didn't manage to find anything.

Full stack trace is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.orm.jpa.HibernateMetricsAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to asynchronously initialize native EntityManagerFactory: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at com.entsorgafin.sr002EagleCloud.Sr002EagleCloudApplication.main(Sr002EagleCloudApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to asynchronously initialize native EntityManagerFactory: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:553) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:497) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:680) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.unwrap(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.orm.jpa.HibernateMetricsAutoConfiguration.bindEntityManagerFactoryToRegistry(HibernateMetricsAutoConfiguration.java:67) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.orm.jpa.HibernateMetricsAutoConfiguration.lambda$bindEntityManagerFactoriesToRegistry$0(HibernateMetricsAutoConfiguration.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:723) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.orm.jpa.HibernateMetricsAutoConfiguration.bindEntityManagerFactoriesToRegistry(HibernateMetricsAutoConfiguration.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:755) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.use42Api(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:78) ~[usertype.spi-6.0.1.GA.jar:na]
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.integrate(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:206) ~[usertype.spi-6.0.1.GA.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.utils.runtime.JavaVersion.<clinit>(JavaVersion.java:16) ~[usertype.spi-6.0.1.GA.jar:na]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You are using jadira userytypes which are probably incompatible with your current version of Java. THat is what the last line of your stacktrace is complaining about. Also you don't get a `NullPointerException` you have an `ExceptionInInitializeError` with a root cause of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. THe `null` in the message doesn't make it a `NullPointerException`!

Comment: Yes, I know, I edited the post just few seconds ago with the new discovery I made by debugging the application, actually I will need to understand how to fix these jadira incompatibility.

Comment: Use a newer version or don't use it.

Comment: I used 6.0.1, upgrading to 7.0.1 solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while using the first release of Java 15 (docker image adoptopenjdk/openjdk15:**jdk-15_36**-alpine-slim).

At `org.jadira.usertype.spi.utils.runtime.JavaVersion` Jadira is expecting an array with two positions:

```
MAJOR_VERSION = Integer.parseInt(versions[0]);
MINOR_VERSION = Integer.parseInt(versions[1]);
```

But in that release it returns an array with only one element: `[15]`.

Upgrading the java version to 15.0.2 solved the problem (docker image adoptopenjdk/openjdk15:jdk-**15.0.2**_7-alpine-slim)

Answer (score 1):

For Java 17 make sure your java version is something like `openjdk version "17.0.2"` and not `jdk-17.jdk`